# Al ejecutar el código solo se muestran factoriales del 0 al 10

Tags: javascript

Debo hacer un pequeño código basado en un ejercicio mediante Javascript y HTML. En el momento de ejecutarlo, tengo que escribir un número cualquiera y que me arroje los factoriales de ese número. Sin embargo, al momento de ejecutarlo solamente me arroja factoriales del 0 al 10, ¿alguien sabe cómo puede solucionarse? les dejo el código.

```
var alerta0 = prompt("Ingresa un numero");

const factorial = numero => {
    if (numero < 0) numero = numero * -1;
    if (numero <= 0) return 1;
    let factorial = 1;
    while (numero > 1) {
        factorial = factorial * numero;
        numero--;
    }
    return factorial;
}

for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    console.log(`El factorial de ${x} es ${factorial(x)}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te indicaron el error que estás cometiendo, voy a mostrarte una forma corta de obtener el factorial de un número empleando una función recursiva:

```js
var x = prompt("Pon un número:"),
    factorial = numero => numero >= 1 ? numero * factorial(--numero) : numero < 0 ? factorial(numero * -1) : 1;

console.log("El factorial de " + (x < 0 ? x * -1 : x) + " es " + factorial(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya casi lo tienes todo listo el detalle esta en que al inicio pides una variable para pedir el número de ejecuciones `var alerta0 = prompt("Ingresa un numero");` y nunca la usas en tu código. Si ves la linea  `for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++)` ahi solo dice que va a ejecutar el código desde el cero hasta que x sea menor a 10 incrementando en uno cada ciclo, lo que necesitas es `for (let x = 0; x <= alerta0; x++)` para indicar que se ejecute hasta que el valor sea menor o igual al que se ingresó. También te recomiendo que valides que el valor ingresado sea un número para evitar errores usando la función `Number.isInteger(p=alerta0)`

Answer (score 0):

A ver, me parece que te has complicado un poco. Como dice el compañero Vago hay variables que no utilizas y operaciones que realizas mal. Para sacar las factoriales con este pequeño código te basta.

```
var x= prompt ("Pon un numero");

    var resu=x;

    for (i=x-1;i>=1;i--)
    {
    resu = resu*i;
    

    document.write ("El numero factorial de "+x+" es "+resu+"<br>")
    }
```